# How can i make my character walk forward?

Tags: animation

[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8DLO.jpg)

I rigged my character and and did a walking animation. Now it walks in place. I was gonna go into object mode and press g and move it. But when i do it it distorts the character. what would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: If you have a standard rig with bones set up the normal way, then you have to go to the top of the hierarchy (the parent bone of all the other bones) and select and move just that.

Comment: Don't animate the mesh, you have to animate the armature in object mode too.

Comment: As FFeller suggests, In Object mode, make your armature follow a curve with the Follow Path constraint